# Are there more different compilers for C++ than for Java?

Tags: java, c++

I am reading a book about C++ and there are a lot of references to the fact that you could better write something a specific way or you might face the situation that when you use a different compiler you may get an error.

For instance here:

```
cout << "The total cost is" << (price + tax);
```

It is stated that when you omit the () there could be a compiler error for some compilers but not all.

I have not ever heard these comments about compilers in Java and read quite a few books, never was it noticed that I had to better write it a specific way or I could get a compiler error. This leads me to the question, is it true that for Java there are only very few compilers with very similar behaviors which is the other way around for C++?

Comment: Java also has a language standard and multiple implementations. The concept of undefined behavior is not as significant to the average Java user most of the time, but difference in your mind between the Oracle java implementation and the java standard should already have been clear, isn't it?  It's not as much "other way round" situation as that you just don't care about any other JVM.  The difference is one of levels of diligence, not underlying realities.

Comment: I'm not bashing Java people here, I'm one of the people who acted like "Visual C++ IS the reference C++ implementation" for many years. :-(

Comment: You're basically asking for the number of non-standards compliant implementations of C++ vs. Java. That is going to be very hard to answer, particularly since both languages have different versions and target many different architectures.

Comment: Two points.  1) There are only a handful of Java compilers.  2) Java environments are subjected to rigorous acceptance testing, intended to allow very little (ideally no) variation from one to the next.  (There is basically only one set of acceptance tests, controlled by Oracle.)

Comment: @juanchopanza even if a question is hard to answer (objectively), I found it often very useful to get a clearer picture about what is important to know and how other people think about when they hear that question. Even if that does not result to an actual full answer. So what you said was also useful :) Thanks Hot Licks and Warren P.

Comment: I find OP's question about "relative quantity" of compilers not very useful.   However, I suspect there aren't really a lot of full C++ compilers either, and each C++ compiler vendor probably tries pretty hard to test their compiler well.  MS's definition of "good" is different than GCC's, so it isn't surprising there are some differences.  The real problem is the complexity of the langauge standard; if it is hard to understand, it is hard to build a compliant compiler.  I think Java is somewhat better than C++ in this regard but they are working hard on becoming just as complicated.

Comment: The statement you quoted isn't correct. The parse for that code is rigorously defined, and should be identical on all conforming C++ compilers. Strange book.

Comment: @IraBaxter - I certainly agree with you that the Java standards folks are working hard at making it complicated and incomprehensible.  I call it "C++ envy".

Comment: It's from Absolute C++ from Walter Savitch page 58 of fifth edition from the international version. If you are interested where I got this example from.

Comment: @Joop Thanks, I will avoid it.

Comment: @WarrenP Thank you. I indeed tried to take this leap into knowing, well said. I will do my best to keep greedy and keep learning. :)